# Less Compiler is not working in PHPStrom 2018.3

Tags: css, less, phpstorm

I am using PHPstrom 2018.3 (latest Version). I am getting this error while I am using `less` to compile through file watcher.

```
Failed to run File Watcher ', Less'.
The watcher has been disabled.
Error: Invalid executable
```

[image: Watcher Image]

Answer (score 0):

', Less' is a curious name for your File Watcher.
As on the screenshot, I would expect 'Less'.

The error "Invalid executable" says either the executable is not there, or it is a different type than a program.

I would say that you can check the name of the executable, which is perhaps case-sensitive ("lessc") or perhaps you need to provide the full path ("C:\...").

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that `lessc` executable was not found on your `%PATH%`.
Please make sure that you have `less` installed via npm (`npm install -g less`) and specify a full path to the installed binary (usually `C:\Users\Your.Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd` on Windows) in a **Program** field.